# MSAL AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode Authentification on Clientside/Browser

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

i want to get access on OneDrive with Microsoft Graph SDK. I have a WebServer running on Azure. My Problem is that i activated 2Factor on microsoft acc and simple give username and password is not working anymore to login without user interaction with Msal. So i tried this:

```
           IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                                              .Create(clientId)
                                              .Build();
            
            Func<DeviceCodeResult, Task> callback = item =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };

            authResult = app.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(scopes, callback)
                                        .ExecuteAsync()
                                        .Result;

            var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
            });
            
            
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider)
```

It stand still on "AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode" and will not doing something anymore.
The only redirect uri is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient
with .NET Framework 4.6.1. I want the login window popup on the browser of the user, not on the azure webserver. How can i pass the login window to the browser of the user OR login without any user interaction with Msal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Get access on behalf of a user authorization method for logging in without the any user interaction.

Please refer this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: I wanted to do this with micsosoft graph SDK, but i done it now without any user login doing this with msal and deamon app, i was to stupid to find any solution to do with user 2FA auth, but in my case it was totaly fine  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet